# I don't know why suddenly mjpg-streamer and webcam stop working

Tags: python, pi-3b+, python-3, webcam

I have made a program that uses three webcams and three ultrasonic sensors using raspberry pi 3 and python 3. When each ultrasonic sensors detect stuff in front of them, webcam take a picture of it. In short, one ultrasonic sensor and one webcam work as a unit and there are 3 units. I made this as a class and each instances uses different gpio pins and camera numbers and runs as a thread.

At now I have added one more webcam to raspberry pi 3 to use it as a cctv. I use mjpg-streamer and it also runs as a thread.

I thought it works well but sometimes mjpg-streamer or a webcam being used to mjpg-streamer suddenly stops working.. below code is part of my program that executes mjpg-streamer.

```
def cctv():
    while True:
        command = 'mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video6 -r 640x480" -o "output_http.so -p 8000 -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www/"'
        output, error = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

cctv_play = threading.Thread(target=cctv, args=())
cctv_play.start()
```

And after mjpg-streamer stops working, a webcam that mjpg-streamer uses doesn't work anymore even if other webcams still works well. I have to reboot raspberry pi 3 to use it again.